# "repeat-x" messing up image in mobile only

Tags: html, css

I have a transparent .png as a repeating background image (repeat-x) that looks great on desktop, but when viewed on mobile, it has what looks like a tiiiiiny sliver of "repeat-y" at the top:

[image]

The source image file is 300px wide and 100px high, and the CSS for this div looks like so:

```
background: url("../img/leaf-pattern-border.png") 0 0 repeat-x scroll transparent;
height: 100px;
```

Other images on the page are fine, so as a test, I changed this to "no-repeat", and the issue went away! So it seems to be the "repeat-x" that is making things weird. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this thin edge/border/artifact thingie?

Comment: Try making it 99px just to see what happens?

Comment: @DannyBarber - sorry for the delay, I was out of town over the weekend. I ended up tweaking the container div to 99px and that did the trick! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tweaking the positioning of the container div and that fixed it. Thanks to @DannyBarber for your help :)